# Undefined offset

Tags: php

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(t.id), SUM(t.num_replies) FROM threads AS t WHERE t.forum_id=$forum_id";

$result = mysql_query($query);
list($num_threads, $num_posts) = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
```

Equals:

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\wamp\www\includes\functions.php on line 11

Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in C:\wamp\www\includes\functions.php on line 11
```

Any ideas how i can get rid of these notices?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://php.net/mysql_fetch_assoc

> `array mysql_fetch_assoc ( resource $result )`
>
> Returns an **associative array**...

http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php

> `array list ( mixed $varname [, mixed $... ] )`
>
> Note: list() only works on **numerical arrays** and assumes the numerical indices start at 0.

You can't assign to variables via `list` from an associative array. Either use `mysql_fetch_row` or, usually better, just use `$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)` and work with `$row` as an array. You don't really want to use `_fetch_row`, since then the sanity of your application hinges on the order the parameters are in in your query, which is something that can break all too easily.

Answer (score 2):

`list()` only works on enumerated arrays. The `mysql_fetch_assoc()` function returns an associative one. Use [`mysql_fetch_row()`](http://php.net/mysql_fetch_row) instead.

Answer (score 1):

This code could error further if you have a syntatical error or theres a problem with mysql_query. If mysql_query does not return a valid result then passing that into mysql_fetch_assoc or mysql_fetch_numeric will cause an error.

I recommend that you validate the return value of mysql_query and mysql_fetch_* before trying to use information from it's return value.

```
$result = mysql_query($query) or die('query error: ' . mysql_error());
$num_threads = $num_posts = 0;
if($result !== false && ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) !== false) {

     $num_threads = $row[0];
     $num_posts   = $row[1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The list() function does only work with numeric array, so you have to use mysql_fetch_row() instead:

```
list($num_threads, $num_posts) = mysql_fetch_row($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned already, you don't need to use `mysql_fetch_assoc` because it will return both numerical and string indeces.. So for two values you'll get four.  **Which is why you have an undefined offset.**  You ask to `list()` two variables from an array that has four values

```
$result = mysql_query($query);
list($num_threads, $num_posts) = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM);
```

By using `mysql_fetch_array` you can specify that you only want the numerical indeces by appending the parameter; `MYSQL_NUM`

Comment: mysql_fetch_assoc() will return only an associative array, mysql_fetch_row() only a numeric and mysql_fetch_array() will return both. That's why you can use the MYSQL_NUM flag on that function. But if you only want numbers, you should take the mysql_fetch_row() function.